# ASP.NET MVC 4, Partial View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to display 4 different lists from 4 different tables, I created a `Partial View` for 4 tables in their respected controller, but its not getting rendered, its giving an error;

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Medical_App.Models.MA_Area', but this > dictionary requires a model item of type  >  'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Medical_App.Models.MA_Area]'.

If there is another way / alternative of doing this, please share.

```
  public PartialViewResult AreaList()
    {
        var result = db.MA_Area.OrderBy(d => d.AreaName);
        return PartialView(result);
    }



@model IEnumerable<Medical_App.Models.MA_Area>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CityId)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AreaName)

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CityId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AreaName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AreaId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.AreaId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AreaId })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Comment: Can you show how your controllers and views?

Comment: Post your views. You are passing a single instance as model while your view is strongly typed to a sequence.

Comment: any tutorial on this topic

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to pass the correct model to the partial view. By default calling a partial view passes the model which the parent view has.

So if you are passing the 4 lists to the main view then each partial call should include the correct IEnumarable object for the view.

You can pass a model with a partial call like this:

```
 @Html.Partial("_partialName", model)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in a collection but trying to display a single instance. You may need something like:

```
@model IEnumerable<Medical_App.Models.MA_Area>
@{foreach(var item in Model)
{
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item .CityId)
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item .AreaName)
}
```

Then you will need to proved some layout structure for each item.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You passed list of items i.e.(List) from your controller/view. But you create the pertial views and accept single item of model i.e. Medical_App.Models.MA_Area on the top of your pertial view(`@model Medical_App.Models.MA_Area`). Pass single instance of model from your controller/view or accept list of model in your pertial view.